# swift Unescaped control character

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get a json from a server and deserialize it, but I try probelas with unescaped control characters.
My code is as follows ...

```
let urlFinal = "http://000.0000.000.000:8080"
        let jsonUrl = urlFinal
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {data, response, error in
            guard data != nil else {
                falha()
                return
            }

            //let json = JSON(data: data!)
            //print(json["ServicoCliente"][0]["id"])

            do {
                let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )
                let J = jsonData as! NSDictionary
                print(jsonData)
                let us = J["ServicoCliente"]
                print(us)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    sucesso()
                });
            } catch _ {
                falha()
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

and I also tried this using Alamofire 3.0:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://000.000.000.000/", parameters: nil)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)     // prints detailed description of all response properties

        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(JSON)")
        }
}
```

And get this error:

> Unescaped control character around character 263

How can I remove characters without escape?

I use X-Code 7.3.1 and Swift 2.3

UPDATE:
Json

```
{"ServicoCliente":[{"id":"195","cliente":"247","enderecoFavoritos":"48","servicoProfissional":"194","ind_estado_cliente":"A","ind_estado_profissional":"","profissional_id":"240","profissional_nome":"PetMax","servicotipo_nome":"Petshop","servicosubtipo_nome":"Tosa ","dta_inc_alt":"2016-11-05 22:56:19.333","ind_finalizado":"N"}]}
```

Comment: I think your JSON isn't valid, try to convert this objc code to Swift http://stackoverflow.com/a/11192483/6366256

Comment: please paste your JSON string here, that would help us to investigate your issue.

Comment: I updated with json, but in one of my tests, I copied and pasted the json in textField and so worked. I think the character was lost in the copy or automaticamet converted into a textfield @Enix

Comment: Does your JSON contain any special whitespace? the error seems coming from the whitespace in the string :`Tosa `.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this, you must convert the data for string, remove characters and then convert to dataonly then deserialize

```
let urlFinal = "http://000.0000.000.000:8080"
let jsonUrl = urlFinal
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)

let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {data, response, error in
guard data != nil else {
    falha()
    return
}

var dataToString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
dataToString = stringByRemovingControlCharacters2(dataToString!)
let ndata = dataToString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

do {
    let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(ndata!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )
    let J = jsonData as! NSDictionary
    print(jsonData)
    let us = J["ServicoCliente"]
    print(us)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        sucesso()
    });
} catch _ {
    falha()
}
}
task.resume()
```

and add the function

```
func stringByRemovingControlCharacters2(string: String) -> String {
let controlChars = NSCharacterSet.controlCharacterSet()
var range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(controlChars)
var mutable = string
while let removeRange = range {
    mutable.removeRange(removeRange)
    range = mutable.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(controlChars)
}

return mutable
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
func string(byRemovingControlCharacters inputString: String) -> String {
    let controlChars = CharacterSet.controlCharacters
    var range = (inputString as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: controlChars)
    if range.location != NSNotFound {
        var mutable = inputString
        while range.location != NSNotFound {
            if let subRange = Range<String.Index>(range, in: mutable) { mutable.removeSubrange(subRange) }
            range = (mutable as NSString).rangeOfCharacter(from: controlChars)
        }
        return mutable
    }
    return inputString
}
```

Comment: infinite loop with this function.

Comment: @Sergio Can you let me know the string that you tried?